# Strange Error while unarchiveObjectWithFile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encoding, nsmutablearray

this is my code:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


//make a file name to write the data to using the
//documents directory:
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/file", documentsDirectory];

array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fullFileName];
```

What's Wrong in my code?

This is the error

```
[__NSArrayM count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xd5864e0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fullFileName];
```

will give you back an autorelease object that will be deallocated at the first appropriate moment. So, when you later access its `count` method, the object is not there anymore. This is what is causing the crash.

A way to fix this is properly managing your array so that it stays there as long as you need it. If you are using ARC, this could mean managing the object through a `strong` property; if you are not using ARC, this involves using `retain`. You do not specify how `array` is declared so I cannot be more precise.

Since you say that the property is declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *array
```

simply doing:

```
self.array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fullFileName];
```

should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't use ARC... I do a @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *array;

Comment: Another question, I don't want an autorelease object... how can I do to force the unarchiveObjectWithFile to return me a NOT-autorelease object?

Comment: doesn't work! This time the error is -[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xd56ea40

Comment: it worked, indeed, since you could pass the statement where it failed, but you have another memory management issue with an NSString. The concept is just the same, retain correctly by means of self.'property_name'... don't forget to release in `dealloc`!

Comment: ok! I will look for my error on the NSString... meanwhile can you explain me why the only "self" before the array can solve my problem?

Comment: the `self`-dot notation will make your compiler use the setter method generated through the `@synthesize` directive, which automatically handle retain/release for you; otherwise, you are assigning directly to the ivar, no retain/release.